# Akka HTTP "actor per request" pattern

Tags: akka, reactive-programming, spray, akka-http

Currently I'm trying to implement the ["actor-per-request" pattern proposed by NET-A-PORTER devs](http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/) in Akka HTTP. The problem I'm facing is that this pattern is not documented anywhere in the docs. There doesn't seem to be a way to do the following:

```
IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(serviceActor, "localhost", port = 38080)
```

How can I use one Akka actor per request without using Spray?

Comment: i would not follow this pattern. Instead, follow the akka examples.

Comment: According to https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18569, this is considered a "fairly common pattern", it's just not documented for akka-http

Comment: Here you can find example app with "actor per request pattern" https://github.com/pjfanning/swagger-akka-http-sample.git

Comment: Thanks for the link, but can it be implemented using `ask`, not `tell`?

Answer (score 1):

The [`HttpExt`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/HttpExt.html) class has a method `bindAndHAndleAsync` that can be used for this purpose.  This method takes in a function with the following signature:

```
handler: (HttpRequest) ⇒ Future[HttpResponse]
```

So, suppose we have an Actor that will produce an `HttpResponse` when asked about an `HttpRequest`:

```
class HttpResponseHandlerActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case _ : HttpRequest => 
      sender() ! HttpResponse(200, entity = "Response From Actor")
  }
}
```

**Inefficient Answer**

Your question explicitly asks how to use 1 Actor per request, to do that we can now use our Actor class to create a handler function:

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

val handler : (HttpRequest) => Future[HttpResponse] = (httpRequest) = {
  val actorHandlerRef = 
    system.actorOf(Props[HttpResponseHandlerActor], "responseActor")

  (actorHandlerRef ask httpRequest).mapTo[HttpResponse]
}
```

We can now use this function to bind our server with:

```
val serverBinding : Future[ServerBinding] = 
  Http().bindAndHandleAsync(handler, "localhost", 8080)
```

**Efficient Answer**

It is usually not necessary to re-create a new Actor for each request, typically you want to create 1 Actor and use it for every request.
Therefore we can move the Actor creation outside of `handler`:

```
val handler : (ActorRef) => (HttpRequest) => Future[HttpResponse] = 
  (actorRef) => (httpRequest) =>
     (actorRef ask httpRequest).mapTo[HttpResponse]
```

The server binding is now slightly modified to:

```
val singleResponseActorRef = 
  system.actorOf(Props[HttpResponseHandlerActor], "responseActor")

val serverBinding : Future[ServerBinding] = 
  Http().bindAndHandleAsync(handler(singleResponseActorRef),
                            "localhost", 
                            8080)
```